# Creating radar image from web api data

Tags: weather-api

To get familiar with front-end web development, I'm creating a weather app.  Most of the tutorials I found display the temperature, humidity, chance of rain, etc.

Looking at the Dark Sky API, I see the "Time Machine Request" returns observed weather conditions, and the response contains a 'precipIntensity' field:  The intensity (in inches of liquid water per hour) of precipitation occurring at the given time. This value is conditional on probability (that is, assuming any precipitation occurs at all).

So, it made me wonder about creating a 'radar image' of precipitation intensity?

Assuming other weather apis are similar, is generating a radar image of precipitation as straightforward as:

1. Create a grid of latitude/longitude coordinates.
2. Submit a request for weather data for each coordinate.
3. Build a color-coded grid of received precipitation intensity values and smooth between them.

Or would that be considered a misuse of the data?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would most likely end up in a very low resolution product. I will explain.

Weather observations come in from input sources ranging from mesonet stations, airports, and other programs like the "citizen weather observer" program. All of these thousands of inputs are input into the [NOAA MADIS system](https://madis-data.ncep.noaa.gov/public/sfcdump.html), a centralized server that stores all observations. The companies that generate the API's pull the data from MADIS.

The problem with the observed conditions is twofold : one is that the stations are highly clustered in urban areas. In Texas, for example - there are 100's of stations in Central TX near the cities of San Antonio and Austin, but 100 miles west there is essentially nothing. To generate  a radar image using this method would involve extreme interpolation- and...

The second problem is observation time. The input from rain gauges are many times delayed several minutes to an hour or more. This would give inaccurate data.

If you wanted a gridded system, the best answer would be to use MRMS (multi-radar-multi-sensor) data from the NWS. It is not an API. These are .grib files that must be downloaded and processed.  [This is the live viewer](https://mrms.nssl.noaa.gov/qvs/product_viewer.php)  and if you want to work on the data itself you can use the [NOAA Weather Climate Toolkit](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/wct/) to view and/or process by GUI or batch process (You can export to geoTIF and colorize it with GDAL tools). The actual MRMS data is located [here](https://mrms.ncep.noaa.gov/data/2D/) and for the basic usage you are looking for, you could use the latest data in the "MergedReflectivityComposite" folder. (That would be how other radar apps show rain.) If you want actual precip intensity, check the "PrecipRate" folder.

For anything else except radar (warning polygons, etc) the NWS has an API that [is located here](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api).

If you have other questions, I will be happy to help.